# The fractional parts of the powers of the golden ratio are not equidistributed in [0,1]

Tags: number-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $$a_n=\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n.$$
For a real number $r$, denote by $\langle r\rangle$ the fractional part of $r$.

Why is the sequence $$\langle a_n\rangle$$ not equidistributed in $[0,1]$?

Comment: It may be helpful to consider $a_n+1$ vs. $a_n^2$ (:

Comment: Have you actually tried computing it?

Comment: I am wondering why $\{ \mbox{frac} (x^n)\}$ is not equidistributed if $\phi^n\to 0\ (\mbox{mod}\ 1)$ holds?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let $\phi'=(1-\sqrt 5)/2$ denote the Galois conjugate of the golden mean $\phi$. 
Then $\phi^n+\phi'^{n}$ is an integer for every $n\in\mathbb N$, i.e.
$$\phi^n+\phi'^{n}\equiv 0\ (\mbox{mod}\ 1).$$

But $|\phi'|<1$, so $\phi'^{n}\to 0$. This implies that $\phi^n\to 0\ (\mbox{mod}\ 1)$.

The property that the sequence  $\{ \mbox{frac} (x^n)\}$ is not equidistributed is shared by other [Pisot numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PisotNumber.html). There is quite a lot of research publications devoted to them.

Answer (score 4):

If you just try it, the fractional part becomes very close to 0 or 1 quickly.  This is because $\phi ^2=\phi +1$.