# $\lfloor x^n\rfloor\lfloor y^n\rfloor$ is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions, square-numbers, perfect-powers

Let $x,y\ge 1$ be non-integer real numbers such that $\lfloor x^n\rfloor\lfloor y^n\rfloor$ is a perfect square for all natural numbers $n$. Does it follow that $x=y$?

From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1926860/when-lfloorab-rfloor-lfloora-rfloor-lfloorb-rfloor) we know the condition under which $\lfloor a\rfloor\lfloor b\rfloor = \lfloor ab\rfloor$. I thought that this implies that for large $n$ it will not be the case that $\lfloor x^n\rfloor\lfloor y^n\rfloor = \lfloor x^ny^n\rfloor$, but now I do not see why.

Comment: @tarthoe I think it might be possible for (1): $\lfloor x^n \rfloor \lfloor y^n \rfloor = \lfloor x^n y^n \rfloor$ for all $n \ge 1$. See the first answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13915/the-fractional-parts-of-the-powers-of-the-golden-ratio-are-not-equidistributed-i). I think if we take $x,y>1$ to have very small galois conjugates, then (1) will hold, due to the criterion given in the first answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1926860/when-lfloorab-rfloor-lfloora-rfloor-lfloorb-rfloor).

Comment: Maybe a starting point would be to have $x = \sqrt{a} \not = y = \sqrt{b}$ with $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$? I don't know if there exist $a, b$ such that $\lfloor x^n\rfloor\lfloor y^n\rfloor$ is a perfect square even for odd $n$ though.

Comment: I didn't clarify in my above comment: that would be if you were trying to find a counterexample for the claim.

Comment: Do you have any examples of such a pair that works for some number of $n$?

Comment: What if we take $x=0.1$ and $y=0.01$.. Does that count as a counter example?

Comment: @Uncool No, the problem requires $x,y\ge 1$.

Comment: oops sorry my bad

Comment: A question that seems simpler : is there an integer $n>0$ such that $\lfloor2,5^n\rfloor$ is a square ?

Answer (score 4):

If the conditions are slightly weakened in either of two ways, or ceiling is used instead of floor, the answer is "no". This is because of the existence of non-integral [Pisot–Vijayaraghavan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number) (hereafter, PV numbers). These interesting algebraic real numbers have the following properties which are important for answering the question:

- PV numbers are greater than 1,
- The product of an integer greater than 0 and a PV number is a PV number,
- A positive integral power of a PV number is a PV number,
- The absolute difference between the $k$-th power of a PV number and the integer nearest that power (hereafter, the "integral disparity") decreases exponentially in $k$.

###### Version 1

Given any $\epsilon > 0$, $\lfloor x^n+\epsilon\rfloor\lfloor y^n+\epsilon\rfloor$ can be a perfect square for all natural numbers $n$, for $x\ne y$.

Given *any* PV number $\alpha$, we can find natural numbers $p$ and $q$, where $q>1$, such that $x=\alpha^{p}$ and $y=q^2\alpha^p$ fulfill the condition. We need $p$ to make sure that the exponential decrease of the integral disparities of powers of $\alpha^p$ is sufficiently strong to overcome the exponential increase caused by multiplying it by powers of $q^2$ when $y$ is exponentiated. $p$ also needs to be chosen large enough so that when $n=1$ the integral disparity of both $x$ and $y$ are already smaller than $\epsilon$. We need $q$ simply to be sure that $x\ne y$.

###### Version 2

$\lfloor x^{2n+1}\rfloor\lfloor y^{2n+1}\rfloor$ can be a perfect square for all natural numbers $n$, for $x\ne y$.

Some quadratic irrational PV numbers $\alpha$ have the property that the sequence $$\alpha^{2n+1} - \lfloor\alpha^{2n+1}\rfloor$$ decreases exponentially for all sufficiently large natural numbers $n$ (in other words, the sufficiently large odd powers of $\alpha$ are always larger than the integer closest to them, with exponentially decreasing integral disparity). The ["golden ratio"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) $\phi={{1+\sqrt{5}}\over 2}$ is a well-known example of such a PV number. Given any such PV number $\alpha$ we can progress similarly as when constructing an example for Version 1: let $x=\alpha^{2p+1}$ and $y=q^2\alpha^{2p+1}$ for natural numbers $p$ and $q$, where $q>1$ and $p$ is sufficiently large.

###### Version 3

$\lceil x^n\rceil\lceil y^n\rceil$ can be a perfect square for all natural numbers $n$, for $x\ne y$.

Some quadratic irrational PV numbers $\alpha$ have the property that the sequence $$\lceil\alpha^n\rceil - \alpha^n$$ decreases exponentially for all sufficiently large natural numbers $n$ (in other words, the sufficiently large powers of $\alpha$ are always smaller than the integer closest to them, with exponentially decreasing integral disparity). $2-\sqrt{2}$ is an example of such a PV number. Given any such PV number $\alpha$ we can progress similarly as when constructing an example for Version 1: let $x=\alpha^p$ and $y=q^2\alpha^p$ for natural numbers $p$ and $q$, where $q>1$ and $p$ is sufficiently large.

---

The three constructions above leave the original question unanswered. If there existed a PV number which has the property that the sequence $$\alpha^{n} - \lfloor\alpha^{n}\rfloor$$ decreases exponentially for all sufficiently large natural numbers $n$, then the answer to the original question would also be "no": however, as a consequence of [the simultaneous version of Dirichlet's approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem), no PV number has that property. In addition, this type of construction could be easily avoided by adding an extra constraint that at least one of $x$ or $y$ is transcendental.